# Append table with position is not exactly showing where it was

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, layout

I am developing a website with Jquery-ui draggables. In the parent div block "container" there are many child draggables which allows user to freely move around the div block.

```
    <div class="container">
      <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="1">Table 1</div>
      <div class="draggable ui-widget-content" id="1">Table 2</div>
      ...
    </div>
```

I implemented a save function which saves the position of each div block as a json string. It stores the position of the draggables and their IDs. So it can be loaded with where they were at last time.

> [{"id":"1","left":"256","top":"226"},{"id":"2","left":"256","top":"632"},{"id":"3","left":"1330","top":"226"},{"id":"4","left":"1330","top":"632"},{"id":"5","left":"818","top":"417"}]

Here's the problem:

I loaded the data from json. It turns out all the position is all wrong.

I recreated using JSFiddle to address the issue: https://jsfiddle.net/braveminds1823/wcmxL2bj/3/

Before saving
[image: Before saving]

After saving, loading the position from json
[image: Loading the position from json]

Edit: I know setting the position to absolute works, but since my website is responsive. The draggables will break out from the container and cover up the web content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can see from what you've provided in the question (not just the fiddle) that your stored values are not correct.

Looking at just "table" - when you load, it's 20x20, but when you move it further left and up, it's now 256x226 - so clearly not saving correctly.

Your issue is with your use of `position`

From MDN [position](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position):

> `relative`
>
> The element is positioned according to the normal flow of the document, 
> and then offset **relative to itself**

so the inside squares do not want `position:relative`, they want `position:absolute`

> `absolute`
>
> The element is **removed from the normal document flow**, and no space is created for the element in the page layout. It is positioned **relative to its closest positioned ancestor**

So two small changes, in the css:

```
.draggable {
   position:absolute;
}
#containment-wrapper {
   position:relative;
}
```

so that the draggable items are positioned absolutely, relative to the parent wrapper.

Otherwise, your code works fine.

Updated fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/hrfx9sky/1/